# assigning a function that returns a list to a list gives an Index Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup

I have a function that returns a list called `get_next_3_numbers_after_match`. Whenever I try to assign that list to another list, it gives an index error. The code is below.

```
def get_next_3_numbers_after_match(MatchList):
     NumList = [Num.strip() for Num in Matchlist if Num[0]=='$' or Num[0].isdigit()==True]
     return NumList

def get_eps():
     for url in list(urls):
         try:
             BASE_URL = "https://www.example.com/"
             soup = BeautiflSoup(requests.get(url, headers).content, 'lxml')
             test = soup.prettify().split('Revenue')
         except IndexError:
             BASE_URL = "https://www.example.com/2"
             soup = BeautiflSoup(requests.get(url, headers).content, 'lxml')
             test = soup.prettify().split('Revenue')[1]
         finally:
             RevenueList = []
           
             RevenueList.extend(get_next_3_numbers_after_match(soup.prettify()\
                        .split('Revenue')[1].split("\n")[0:21]))
     return RevenueList
```

Running the for loop gives this error:
`RevenueList.extend() IndexError: List index out of range`

Comment: `soup.prettify().split('Revenue')[1].split("\n")` likely doesn't have 20 elements in one iteration of the loop. Try slitting that line into separate lines and checking the output at each step to verify that what you're getting is actually what you expect

Comment: Can you share the URL and what information do you want to get?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I want to get sec stock data. The URL for apple is:https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/R2.htm. The data I want to get is the revenue data, which has 3 columns, and I want all of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract information from this table, you can use this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/R2.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td') if td.get_text(strip=True)]
    if len(tds) == 4:
        all_data.append(tds)

for row in all_data:
    print('{:<50} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
Net sales                                          $ 260,174  $ 265,595  $ 229,234 
Cost of sales                                      161,782    163,756    141,048   
Gross margin                                       98,392     101,839    88,186    
Research and development                           16,217     14,236     11,581    
Selling, general and administrative                18,245     16,705     15,261    
Total operating expenses                           34,462     30,941     26,842    
Operating income                                   63,930     70,898     61,344    
Other income/(expense), net                        1,807      2,005      2,745     
Income before provision for income taxes           65,737     72,903     64,089    
Provision for income taxes                         10,481     13,372     15,738    
Net income                                         $ 55,256   $ 59,531   $ 48,351  
Basic (in dollars per share)                       $ 11.97    $ 12.01    $ 9.27    
Diluted (in dollars per share)                     $ 11.89    $ 11.91    $ 9.21    
Basic (in shares)                                  4,617,834  4,955,377  5,217,242 
Diluted (in shares)                                4,648,913  5,000,109  5,251,692 
Net sales                                          $ 213,883  $ 225,847  $ 196,534 
Cost of sales                                      144,996    148,164    126,337   
Net sales                                          46,291     39,748     32,700    
Cost of sales                                      $ 16,786   $ 15,592   $ 14,711
```

---

Or use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/R2.htm'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS - USD ($) shares in Thousands, $ in Millions 12 Months Ended                            
   CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS - USD ($) shares in Thousands, $ in Millions   Sep. 28, 2019 Sep. 29, 2018 Sep. 30, 2017
0                                           Net sales                                       $ 260,174     $ 265,595     $ 229,234
1                                       Cost of sales                                          161782        163756        141048
2                                        Gross margin                                           98392        101839         88186
3                                 Operating expenses:                                             NaN           NaN           NaN
4                            Research and development                                           16217         14236         11581
5                 Selling, general and administrative                                           18245         16705         15261
6                            Total operating expenses                                           34462         30941         26842
7                                    Operating income                                           63930         70898         61344
8                         Other income/(expense), net                                            1807          2005          2745
9            Income before provision for income taxes                                           65737         72903         64089
10                         Provision for income taxes                                           10481         13372         15738
11                                         Net income                                        $ 55,256      $ 59,531      $ 48,351
12                                Earnings per share:                                             NaN           NaN           NaN
13                       Basic (in dollars per share)                                         $ 11.97       $ 12.01        $ 9.27
14                     Diluted (in dollars per share)                                         $ 11.89       $ 11.91        $ 9.21
15       Shares used in computing earnings per share:                                             NaN           NaN           NaN
16                                  Basic (in shares)                                         4617834       4955377       5217242
17                                Diluted (in shares)                                         4648913       5000109       5251692
18                                           Products                                             NaN           NaN           NaN
19                                          Net sales                                       $ 213,883     $ 225,847     $ 196,534
20                                      Cost of sales                                          144996        148164        126337
21                                           Services                                             NaN           NaN           NaN
22                                          Net sales                                           46291         39748         32700
23                                      Cost of sales                                        $ 16,786      $ 15,592      $ 14,711
```

---

EDIT: To get ids from first column, you can do this:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/R2.htm'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    tds = [td for td in tr.select('td') if td.get_text(strip=True)]
    if len(tds) == 4:
        tds[0] = re.search(r"'(.*?)'", tds[0].a['onclick']).group(1)
        tds[1:] = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tds[1:]]
        all_data.append(tds)

for row in all_data:
    print('{:<90} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
defref_us-gaap_RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax                         $ 260,174  $ 265,595  $ 229,234 
defref_us-gaap_CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold                                                  161,782    163,756    141,048   
defref_us-gaap_GrossProfit                                                                 98,392     101,839    88,186    
defref_us-gaap_ResearchAndDevelopmentExpense                                               16,217     14,236     11,581    
defref_us-gaap_SellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense                                      18,245     16,705     15,261    
defref_us-gaap_OperatingExpenses                                                           34,462     30,941     26,842    
defref_us-gaap_OperatingIncomeLoss                                                         63,930     70,898     61,344    
defref_us-gaap_NonoperatingIncomeExpense                                                   1,807      2,005      2,745     
defref_us-gaap_IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIncomeTaxesExtraordinaryItemsNoncontrollingInterest 65,737     72,903     64,089    
defref_us-gaap_IncomeTaxExpenseBenefit                                                     10,481     13,372     15,738    
defref_us-gaap_NetIncomeLoss                                                               $ 55,256   $ 59,531   $ 48,351  
defref_us-gaap_EarningsPerShareBasic                                                       $ 11.97    $ 12.01    $ 9.27    
defref_us-gaap_EarningsPerShareDiluted                                                     $ 11.89    $ 11.91    $ 9.21    
defref_us-gaap_WeightedAverageNumberOfSharesOutstandingBasic                               4,617,834  4,955,377  5,217,242 
defref_us-gaap_WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding                             4,648,913  5,000,109  5,251,692 
defref_us-gaap_RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax                         $ 213,883  $ 225,847  $ 196,534 
defref_us-gaap_CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold                                                  144,996    148,164    126,337   
defref_us-gaap_RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax                         46,291     39,748     32,700    
defref_us-gaap_CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold                                                  $ 16,786   $ 15,592   $ 14,711
```

Comment: Hey, this is great! I don't know if it is possible, but each Id (e.g. Net Sales, Gross Margin) has a identifier that you can see if you view the page source. For the first Net Sales Column, the "identifier" is 'defref_us-gaap_RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax'.  Is there any way to replace stuff like Net Sales with their true identifier?